# Specific ls output

Tags: ls, recursive, directory-listing

Right now I'm calling the the following command `ls -R` and am receiving an output like this:

```
.:
file.txt script.php

./dir:
file.txt other.java
```

Is it possible to get the output to look like this:

```
./file.txt ./script.php ./dir/file.txt ./dir/other.java
```

I've looked through the parameters of `ls` and can't seem to find anything that will do what I want.

Comment: Not a good idea once your filenames start having space characters in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
find . -type f -printf '%p '
```

It will output one reeeally long line of the file names (incl. path) separated by space. There will be one bonus space at the end of it, too.

(You can trade that in for a newline by piping to `sed 's/ $/\n/'`, which might be a good idea anyway.)